# How to apply MFA auth in PHP native project

Tags: php, multi-factor-authentication

I have a native PHP project using SESSIONS for logging users in. Now the client needs to implement MFA within the project and require to request the confirmation code every 30 days of last verification.

Is there any documentation or resources to learn how to implement MFA on native PHP project? I searched but there aren't a lot of resources demonstrate how to do this thing on native PHP app.

Comment: I literally had this exact same project requirement about a year ago. I used this PHP library and it worked great https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator. The new code every 30 days was set with a cookie that expired once every 30 days. The only limitation you might have is it works with google MFA. You might have to go with a paid service like twilio if you want to be able to use something like Authy or other MFA apps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Without sharing your attempts, it's close to impossible to provide proper help

Comment: @NicoHaase I did not make attempts, I want to understand how to implement first، and if there are any packages can help me or should i do it without packages

Comment: Searching for libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: i searched already and can't find any helpful thing thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use  PHP library for Two Factor Authentication package: https://github.com/RobThree/TwoFactorAuth

This library can use Microsoft TFA authentication service on your mobile (works on Android and IOS). Session life control can be achieved by a custom cron job or PHP configuration `session.gc_maxlifetime`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).